# Selected days random order, find the earliest and latest

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have got an array of days:

```
let days = [ 'monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday', 'friday', 'saturday', 'sunday' ]
```

Obviously the keys above are from 0 - 6. I use these days to generate a list, a user can then selecte and deselect days from this list. So if they deselect Monday and then select Sunday I now have a `selected` array:

```
let selected = [ 'sunday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday', 'friday', 'saturday' ]
```

I then want to format the selected dates and display it to the user, but of course using the code below I will get **Sunday - Saturday**, when really I want **Tuesday - Sunday**.

```
let dayOne = this.selected[0];
let dayTwo = this.selected[this.selected.length - 1];

if (dayOne === undefined && dayTwo === undefined) return;

return dayOne.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + dayOne.slice(1) + ' - ' + dayTwo.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + dayTwo.slice(1);
```

What's a nice and clear way to do this?

Comment: @Artyom there is

Comment: What causes `selected` array to get out of order in the first place?

Comment: @charlietfl By the user deselecting and selecting different days, I just push them or splice them depending if they are already within the array. The `days` array remains untouched, it's the `selected` array which changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My recommendation:

Use a simple integer list [0...6] and use that instead. I'm pretty sure you have 7 checkboxes holding the weekday names as values. Use the numbers as values instead.

Then, when you need the array with day names, do this:

```js
const weekdays = [ 'monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday', 'friday', 'saturday', 'sunday' ];
let selected = [5,2,4,1]; //unsorted array
selected.sort(); //careful here
let selecteddays = selected.map(d => weekdays[d]);
console.log(selecteddays);
```

This `sort()` can be problematic, gotta be careful with it.
Check this on how to properly sort numeric arrays: [How to sort an array of integers correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1063007/how-to-sort-an-array-of-integers-correctly)

Comment: Should be careful using `sort()` on number array without a numeric sort callback. It works here because range is very small but if it went 1-20 would not work

Answer (score 1):

You can sort by comparing the index in original `days` array

```js
let days = [ 'monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday', 'friday', 'saturday', 'sunday' ]
let selected = ['saturday', 'friday', 'wednesday']

selected.sort((a,b) => days.indexOf(a) - days.indexOf(b))

console.log(selected)
```

Comment: Thanks, I prefer the other answer though actually. Indexes are probably better to use.